# .NET Runtime on arm64, libssl issue

Tags: .net, arm64, libssl, armbian

I use Orange PI 3 LTS with latest version armbian (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS). NET 5.0.17.

So, i installed dotnet runtime:

```
root@orangepi3-lts:~# dotnet --info

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.17
  Commit:  6a98414363

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Next, on Visiual Studio publishing typed `<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>`  and tried to launch my .NET5 console app on device:

```
root@orangepi3-lts:~# dotnet "/opt/Services/Example/Example.WebApi.dll"
No usable version of libssl was found
Aborted
```

*No usable version of libssl...*, **how can i fix it?**

And tried to change ssl in *openssl.cnf* and run *apt install libssl-dev* but nothing changed.

```
[ default_conf ]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, on .net 6 simple console web application now is working. I think the problem was in my hands and some our libraries, which are not working under arm64.